# Saving the XML results to variable or table in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, database, stored-procedures

How can I save a XML to variable or table which is generated by SQL stored procedure?

Here's my sample:

```
DECLARE @ReportResultXml TABLE(RXml XML)    
DECLARE @ResultXml  XML = NULL

INSERT @ReportResultXml EXEC (@Script + ' FOR XML RAW, ROOT, XMLSCHEMA, ELEMENTS')
SELECT @ResultXml = RXml FROM @ReportResultXml
EXEC Repor.ProcInsert 1, @ResultXml

SELECT @ResultXml
```

The `@Script` variable contains this SQL query:

```
DECLARE @PeriodID INT
SET @PeriodID = 12
SELECT TOP 10 PeriodID, Name
FROM Agent.Points
WHERE PeriodID = @PeriodID
```

That statement will generate the following error:

> The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to find your solution:

```
declare @script nvarchar(max)
set @script = 'select 1 as a, 2 as b for xml raw'

declare @ReportResultXml table (RXml XML)
declare @ResultXml xml

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = 'set @ResultXml = (' + @script + ')'
execute sp_ExecuteSQL @sql, N'@ResultXml xml output', @ResultXml output

insert into @ReportResultXml select @ResultXml

select * from @ReportResultXml
```